# How to explode values of find query in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i am getting output like this..

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [location_id] => 4,3
    )
)
```

i need to explode values of location_id and pass in below find condition....but i am getting error explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

```
public function getUserLocations() {  
    $this->loadModel('User');  
    $user_id = $this->Session->read('LoginUser.id');
    $locationid = $this->User->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id' => $user_id,
            'User.is_deleted' => 0,
            'User.status' => 1
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'location_id'
        )
    ));
    $data = explode(",", $locationid);
    print_r($data);
    exit();
    $this->loadModel('Location');  
    $getlocations = $this->Location->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Location.id' => $data,
            'Location.is_deleted' => 0,
            'Location.status' => 1
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Location.id',
            'Location.location_name'
        ),
        'order' => 'location_name ASC'
    ));            
    $this->set('getlocations', $getlocations);
}
```

Comment: `explode(",",$locationid);` should be `explode(",",$locationid['User']['location_id']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$new_exploded_arr = explode(",", $your_output_arr['User']['location_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

$exploded_arr = explode(',', $expected_arr['User']['location_id']);